# Minimal faithful modules for hereditary algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

A module $M$ is minimal faithful if $M$ is faithful and if we remove any indecomposable summand of $M$, then $M$ is not faithful anymore.

> Question: Is there a classification of minimal faithful modules for path algebra $KQ$ with acyclic $Q$?

In linear oriented Dynkin type $A_n$, there is a unique such module namely the unique projective-injective indecomposable module. In non-linear $A_n$ type there can be more minimal faithful modules.